# Display the alt attribute under image on iframe html

Tags: javascript, html, image, iframe, innerhtml

I have this basic website that has multiple images and I want to display the 'alt' attributes under each image via javascript. I have tried a few ideas and I made it work. But my problem now is that I want this basic website to be loaded by another, a parent website, via 'iframe'.

So I have this line of code into the parent website

```
<iframe id="iframeID" name="iframeName" src="...my basic website" scrolling="auto" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="700"></iframe>
```

and it loads the basic website with the images. The website with the images has this kind of code:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="imageOne.jpg" alt="An image of an elephant">
    </div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

In the parent website, under

```
<script></script>
```

I have this code:

```
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
var imageContainers = gallery.getElementsByClassName('image-container');

// Loop through the image containers:
    for (var i = 0; i < imageContainers.length; i++) {

    var image = imageContainers[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    var caption = document.createElement('span');
    caption.innerHTML = image.alt;
    window.frames[0].document.getElementById('gallery').getElementsByClassName('image-container')[i].appendChild(caption);
    }
```

and nothing happens.

When I have the exact same code but with a different end line in the 'script' of the basic website where the images are

```
imageContainers[i].appendChild(caption);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('gallery').getElementsByClassName('image-container')[i].appendChild(caption);
```

but without the

```
window.frames[0]
```

and I load that website via 'iframe' or just open it via its link, all works. I just can't seem to make the 'alt' attributes or any text to display in the 'iframe' HTML from the parent website. I can change the style of the iframe HTML but cannot add text into a 'div' or 'span' or anything. And I do not understand why.

If you could help it would be great.

Thank you.

p.s: I need the basic website to be loaded by the parent website via 'iframe'; the javascript that displays the 'alt' attributes has to be in the parent website, not in the one that is being loaded

p.s.2: both websites are in the same domain and both are mine

Comment: Is the website in the `<iframe>` of a different origin? Due to the same-origin policy of JS, you cannot use JS on the parent page to read contents from the child frame if they are not from the same domain.

Comment: both websites are mine, so same domain; I can change the style but not add new content